How to disable a route (or allow duplicates) from the parent controller class
I want a child controller to have query parameters while the default implementation in the base controller has none. I have a base controller that all other controllers inherit from. The controller has a Get() method:
public abstract class BaseEntityController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("")]
  public virtual Task<IActionResult> Get()
  {
      DoSomeGetAllFunctionallity();
  }
}

In one of the child controllers I want to have some query parameters in the for the get all method:
public abstract class ChildController : BaseEntityController
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery(Name = "param-1")] int? param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param-2")] bool param2 = false)
  {
    DoSomeGetAllFunctionallity(param1, param2);
  }
}

When trying to test this with Swagger I get the error:
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: 'Conflicting method/path combination "GET endpoint" for actions - path-to-controller.Get, path-to-controller.Get. Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround'
I would be happy with the following two outcomes:

Override the route of the base class to disable it

[Route(disable: true)]
public override Task<IActionResult> Get() => throw new NotImplementedException();


Pass the default parameters through to the other method

public override Task<IActionResult> Get() => Get(null, false);

I have not found a solution for either of the two outcomes.

Can't you remove the attributes on one of the methods?

I can remove the attributes on the child controller methods, but then I will not be able to use query parameters then. I can't remove the attributes in the base controller because it is used by all controllers in the project.

You can remove the attributes on the base controller methods, then you can call return base.Get() when param1 and param2 are null (change param2 to bool?).

Yes, but as mentioned in my previous comment, I cannot change the implementation of the BaseEntityController because the whole project uses it.

Then you can set Route("", Order = -1) on the child class method.

The order determines the order of route execution, but there will still be 2 methods for the same action.

I think you are fighting the framework by starting off with a bad implementation. You really shouldn't have the Get method in the base class if it isn't always required.

Only the method with the lowest order will be executed.

I found an answer that is close to yours @shingo, the [NonAction] decorater disables the action of a method.

I found an answer that works for me. An action method can be disabled by adding the [NonAction] attribute. This way the child controller can disable the parent action method and make its own for the same route.
public abstract class ChildController : BaseEntityController
{
  [NonAction]
  public override Task<IActionResult> Get() => throw new NotImplementedException();

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery(Name = "param-1")] int? param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param-2")] bool param2 = false)
  {
    DoSomeGetAllFunctionallity(param1, param2);
  }
}


Why you set the method's name as "Get"？Are you use the ServiceStack？
If yes,then you can rename it to "Any" like these:
public abstract class ChildController : BaseEntityController
{
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Any([FromQuery(Name = "param-1")] int? 
  param1, [FromQuery(Name = "param-2")] bool param2 = false)
 {
  DoSomeGetAllFunctionallity(param1, param2);
 }
}


The method name does not matter, it's the fact that there are 2 methods that have the same route ([Route("")]

Ok.Then why you use the same route？

because in each controller I want a get all with the route "api/entity", so the base entity controller has a method with that route. But in one controller I want that same get all route "api/entity" to have some query parameters: "api/entity?param-1=text&param-2=text". This results in two implementations for the same route
